# jq filter to convert Elasticsearch result to CSV

Tags: csv, filter, jq

I'm trying to convert my json search result from Elasticsearch to a csv format using jq.

My actual jq command looks like this:

```
.aggregations["byLabels"].buckets | map({key,doc_count,range: .byRange.buckets | map({str:(.from_as_string + "-" + .to_as_string), dc:.doc_count} | [.str, .dc])} | flatten )
```

And the actual result:

```
[
  [
    "Page 1",
    15001,
    "0.0-1000.0",
    7,
    "1000.0-2000.0",
    1005,
    "2000.0-",
    8907
  ],
  [
    "Page 2",
    340,
    "0.0-1000.0",
    23,
    "1000.0-2000.0",
    261,
    "2000.0-",
    18
  ]
]
```

But the csv output I need should look like this (with or without quotation marks):

```
"Page1",15001,"0.0-1000.0",7,1000.0-2000.0,1005,"2000.0-*",8907
"Page2",340,"0.0-1000.0",23,1000.0-2000.0,261,"2000.0-*",18
```

I tried to add a additional add[] or flatten or join(",") filters, but only get errors when trying to use |@csv.

This is my first time I use jq, so I think this is not a problem for any experiences jq user.

The original json file looks like this:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 51632,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "byLabels" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 2478,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "Page 1",
        "doc_count" : 15001,
        "byRange" : {
          "buckets" : {
            "0.0-1000.0" : {
              "from" : 0.0,
              "from_as_string" : "0.0",
              "to" : 1000.0,
              "to_as_string" : "1000.0",
              "doc_count" : 7
            },
            "1000.0-2000.0" : {
              "from" : 1000.0,
              "from_as_string" : "1000.0",
              "to" : 2000.0,
              "to_as_string" : "2000.0",
              "doc_count" : 1005
            },
            "2000.0-*" : {
              "from" : 2000.0,
              "from_as_string" : "2000.0",
              "doc_count" : 8907
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "key" : "Page 2",
        "doc_count" : 340,
        "byRange" : {
          "buckets" : {
            "0.0-1000.0" : {
              "from" : 0.0,
              "from_as_string" : "0.0",
              "to" : 1000.0,
              "to_as_string" : "1000.0",
              "doc_count" : 23
            },
            "1000.0-2000.0" : {
              "from" : 1000.0,
              "from_as_string" : "1000.0",
              "to" : 2000.0,
              "to_as_string" : "2000.0",
              "doc_count" : 261
            },
            "2000.0-*" : {
              "from" : 2000.0,
              "from_as_string" : "2000.0",
              "doc_count" : 18
            }
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show the original json document?

Comment: Original post edited and attached the original document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@csv only works on a flat array, so you could add '| .[] | @csv' to your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the solution :-)